# Designing a rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm going to develop a university management project, where, includes some constraints,

1. there are some semesters from 1 to 8 or more
2. there are some subjects where a subject can be taken in different semesters, and so that a semester has many subjects.
3. the students with an unique id can register to a semester. Form the subjects belonging to that semester he can choose some subjects.
4. a student can not register to the previously registered semester. but he can register to another semester.

how can i design this??

Comment: Like all of us do - sit down with a piece of paper and a pencil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models are something like this:

```
class Semester < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subjects
  has_many :semester_students
  has_many :students, :through => :semester_students
end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :semester
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :semester_students
  has_many :semesters, :through => :semester_students
end
```

Use foreign key(semester_id, student_id, subject_id and so on) and association table(semester_students) to implement the one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationships.